# Laravel: Retrieve Listing by category and location, including all child categories and locations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I am attempting to fetch Listings based on both category and location, encompassing all child locations as well. I have provided a screenshot of the filter form for reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLqKl.png)

Tables
Here's categories table :

```
| id    | parent_id     | name          |
|----   |-----------    |-------------  |
| 1     | NULL          | Electronics   |
| 2     | 1             | Computers     |
| 3     | 2             | Accessories   |
| 4     | 3             | Keyboards     |
```

and here's my Listing table :

```
| id    | category_id   | name          |
|----   |-------------  |-----------    |
| 1     | 2             | Product 1     |
| 2     | 3             | Product 2     |
| 3     | 4             | Product 3     |
```

Here's location table :

```
| id    | parent_id     | name          |
|----   |-----------    |-------------  |
| 1     | NULL          | Texas         |
| 2     | 1             | London        |
| 3     | 2             | United States |
| 4     | 3             | Canada        |
```

Using Below code in both models of category and location:

```
    public function childrenRecursive()
    {
        return $this->children()->with('childrenRecursive', 'rListing');
    }
```

When a user selects a location, the system retrieves all its children locations. Similarly, when the user selects both location and category, the system should search for the category based on the location, encompassing all children locations, rather than focusing on a specific category.

Using this code But it's for specific category and location

```
$listing_items = DB::table('listings');
        
        if($request->text != '') {
            $listing_items = $listing_items->where('listings.listing_name','LIKE', '%'.$request->text.'%');
        }

        if($request->category != '') {
            $listing_items = $listing_items->where('listings.listing_category_id',$request->category);
        }

        if($request->location != '') {
            $listing_items = $listing_items->where('listings.listing_location_id',$request->location);
        }        

        $listing_items = $listing_items->join('listing_categories', 'listings.listing_category_id','=', 'listing_categories.id');
        $listing_items = $listing_items->join('listing_locations', 'listings.listing_location_id','=', 'listing_locations.id');
        $listing_items = $listing_items->where('listings.listing_status','Active');
        $listing_items = $listing_items->select('listings.*',
        'listing_categories.listing_category_name',
        'listing_categories.listing_category_slug',
        'listing_locations.listing_location_name',
        'listing_locations.listing_location_slug');
        $listing_items = $listing_items->paginate(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

In ListingCategory:

```
  public function getAllChildCategoryIds()
{
    if($this->childrenRecursive->isNotEmpty())
    {
        $childIds = $this->childrenRecursive->pluck('id')->all();
    
        foreach ($this->childrenRecursive as $child) {
            $childIds = array_merge($childIds, $child->getAllChildCategoryIds());
        }
        $childIds = array_merge($childIds, [$this->id]);
    }else{
        $childIds = [$this->id];
    }
    return $childIds;
}
```

Then you can use the function like this:

```
$listing_items = DB::table('listings');
    
    if($request->text != '') {
        $listing_items = $listing_items->where('listings.listing_name','LIKE', '%'.$request->text.'%');
    }

    if($request->category != '') {
        $category = ListingCategory::with(['rListing', 'childrenRecursive', 'childrenRecursive.rListing'])->find($request->category);
        $categoryIds = $category->getAllChildCategoryIds();
        $listing_items->whereIn('listings.listing_category_id', $categoryIds);
    }

    if($request->location != '') {
        $location = ListingLocation::with(['rListing', 'childrenRecursive', 'childrenRecursive.rListing'])->find($request->location);
        $locationIds = $location->getAllChildLocationIds();
        $listing_items->whereIn('listings.listing_location_id', $locationIds);
    }        

    $listing_items->join('listing_categories', 'listings.listing_category_id', '=', 'listing_categories.id');
    $listing_items->join('listing_locations', 'listings.listing_location_id', '=', 'listing_locations.id');
    $listing_items = $listing_items->where('listings.listing_status','Active');
    $listing_items = $listing_items->select('listings.*',
    'listing_categories.listing_category_name',
    'listing_categories.listing_category_slug',
    'listing_locations.listing_location_name',
    'listing_locations.listing_location_slug');
    $listing_items = $listing_items->paginate(4);
```

***Used this code hope it will work for you***